# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var container = document.getElementById("f2");
text = text.replace(/\:\)/g, '<img src="images.jpg" border="0">');
```

In this code am getting this error.
In the starting of function `text` is defined as `var`.
f2 code is here:

```
     <table style='width: 100%'>
        <tr>
        <td>

                     <textarea id="fname" class="span5 chattextarea" style="resize: none;"            cols="240" rows="13" disabled="disabled" style="float:centre" style="background-color: transparent" style="border: 3px dotted #f7730E;"></textarea>
   </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="text" id="f2" style="width: 440; height:100%"  class="chattextarea" autocomplete="off"  onkeyup="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) testChat();" placeholder= "Type your Message"></input>
 <input type="button" class="btn-success" style="width: 50px" value="Send" onclick="testChat()"></input>
  </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Where is `text` defined?

Comment: You haven't defined the variable `text`.

Comment: Javascript may be magical, but not THAT magical.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the variable `text` anywhere.

Change `text.replace()` to `container.innerHTML.replace()`

and also I suspect that you want to be doing this afterwards

```
container.innerHTML = text;
```

so that your `container` element gets the image as it's new content.

Comment: Then your `f2` element is probably not in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = document.getElementById("f2").innerHTML;  // incase you use innerHTML
var text = container.replace(/\:\)/g, '<img src="images.jpg" border="0">');
```

incase if it is about the value of element `f2` then

```
var container = document.getElementById("f2").value;  // incase you use value
var text = container.replace(/\:\)/g, '<img src="images.jpg" border="0">');
```